# Gradients of two functions with the same level sets are parallel for all points in the intersection of the level sets

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Is the intuition behind this statement, based on : 
1. The definition that a gradient is perpendicular to the level curves
2. Since the level sets are the same for both functions, the corresponding gradients are parallel to each other?

Comment: If we had two functions, $f$ and $g$, by them having the same level set do you mean $f=c$ is the same level set as $g=c$ or do you mean $f=g=c$? for some constant $c$.

Comment: the former; in particular; L1={x|f(x)=t}, L2={x|g(x)=t}

Answer (score 0):

No this is not quite the case although it is tempting to believe. One such counter example is as follows:
Let $f(x,y,z)=x$ and $g(x,y,z)=z$. Then lets consider $f=1$ and $g=1$.

- The level surface for $f$, $x=1$, gives us a vertical plane with a constant gradient vector $<1,0,0>$.
- The level surface for $g$, $z=1$, gives us a horizontal plane with a constant gradient vector $<0,0,1>$.

We know that these two level surfaces intersect at a line, however their gradients are never parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the level set are regular. That means, we can parametrize the level set as $\vec{x}(s_1, s_2, ..., s_{n-1})$. Also if we assume two functions having the same level set means if $f = g = t$, then we can use the same paramertization to represent them
$$\vec{x}(s_1, s_2, ..., s_{n-1}, t)$$
such that
$$f(\vec{x}(s_1, s_2, ..., s_{n-1}, t)) = g(\vec{x}(s_1, s_2, ..., s_{n-1}, t))= t$$
Then we have
$$\nabla f \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t} = 1$$
$$\nabla f \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial s_i} = 0$$

$$\nabla g \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t} = 1$$
$$\nabla g \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial s_i} = 0$$

As long as the level is not degerated, $( \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t},\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial s_1}, ..., \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial s_{n-1}} )$ is invertible, it is true under my assumptions of the OP. If the level set is degenerated, then it could be wrong.